# Number of distinct $n$-ary relations on a set with $k$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, relations

On the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#The_number_of_binary_relations) page for binary relations, there's a table that includes the number of distinct binary relations given an $n$-element set: $2^{n^2}$. They also include how many distinct equivalence relations, total orders, partial orders, etc.

I know the other ones only make sense in the context of binary relations but, how might we generalize this result and find the number of distinct $n$-ary relations given a set of $k$ elements?

Comment: By $n$-ary relation on a set $K$ of $k$ elements, do you just mean a subset of $K^n = \underbrace{K \times \cdots \times K}_n$?

Comment: Yes. (I need ten more characters to post this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A n-ary relation on a set K of k elements is a subset of K$^n$.
K$^n$ has k$^n$ elements.
Thus there is how many n-ary relations?

Comment: So is it $2^{k^n}$ since we can either include the element or not?